# Add styles to a dynamic repeater control in code behind

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, repeater

This is the code I am using to generate a repeater control dynamically, bound to SQL. I have to do it with C# coding only. There's just a "panel" placed in the aspx part. I am able to get the output using this. But its coming in the label where I am not able to apply any styles to it.
I have attached a screenshot. Somebody please help me with applying styles to the output. Like alternating colors, etc.. Thanks a ton.

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{    // Repeater Control Databinding using Datasource
        Repeater Repeater1 = new Repeater();
        //Repeater1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        //Repeater1.DataBind();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        string connStr = ("Data Source=LFVMOSS;Initial Catalog=DB_SFG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=DB_SFG;Password=sfg");

        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand mySqlSelect = new SqlCommand("select * from List1", mySQLconnection);
        mySqlSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlSelect); DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

        // Repeater Control Databinding using Datasource
        Repeater1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        Repeater1.DataBind();        
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Close();
        }           
        foreach (RepeaterItem repeatItem in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            // if condition to add HeaderTemplate Dynamically only Once
            if (repeatItem.ItemIndex == 0)
            {
                RepeaterItem headerItem = new RepeaterItem(repeatItem.ItemIndex, ListItemType.Header);
                HtmlGenericControl hTag = new HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                hTag.InnerHtml = "Employee Names";
                repeatItem.Controls.Add(hTag);
            }

            // Add ItemTemplate DataItems Dynamically
            RepeaterItem repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(repeatItem.ItemIndex, ListItemType.Item);
           Label lbl = new Label();                   
           lbl.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} <br />", myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[repeatItem.ItemIndex]["id"], myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[repeatItem.ItemIndex]["Name"]);                     
           repeatItem.Controls.Add(lbl);

            // Add SeparatorTemplate Dynamically
            repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(repeatItem.ItemIndex, ListItemType.Separator);
            LiteralControl ltrlHR = new LiteralControl();
            ltrlHR.Text = "<hr />";
            repeatItem.Controls.Add(ltrlHR);
        }

        // Add Repeater Control as Child Control
        // of Panel Control
        Panel1.Controls.Add(Repeater1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Note: The output should be like a table.The numbers in one column and the alphabets in another column.

Comment: `OnDataBound` event on `Repeater` to makeyour thing cleaner

Comment: i have no repeater control on the aspx page.All my code is code behind only.

Comment: but you can use `event` of `Repeater` from code behind like this:
`Repeater1.ItemDataBound +=new RepeaterItemEventHandler(Repeater1_ItemDataBound);` and in method Repeater1_ItemDataBound you can make all your logic

Comment: If you want it to look like a table and to style alternate rows, why not output with table tags and use css to style the alternate rows? Make your life easy by picking the tags that do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add style to a control, use the `Style` property.

```
 lbl.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "green");
```

But as the comments above suggest, you are going about this in a contrary manner. If you want output like a table, use a `<table>` tag